# How to set the expiration date for a long time for mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build my mongoose schema and need to set the expiration date for 3 months by now.
so *3 months = 7776000 seconds*
I added in my schema

```
createdAt: {
              type: date,
              default: Date.now(),
              index: {
                   expireAfterSeconds: 7776000
              }
}
```

I tried many methods from StackOverflow, but I didn't succeeded with it.

Do you guys have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `createIndex` command provided by MongoDB and Mongoose:

```js
  schema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 7776000 });
```

Read more in these relevant [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time) and [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

Comment: I tried it, i set the expireAfterSeconds to 60, so It changed nothing

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the solution that worked for me:

```
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: '5m',
}
```

And then I modify the time depending on my needs.